# Create local repository on BitBucket and allow access to team

Tags: git, macos, bitbucket

I want to create a repository on my local system and use it as server. I don't want to save my files on Git/BitBucket server.

I have checked that it is possible in free account of BitBucket but could not find a tutorial specific to my requirement. I checked [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/GitHosting/article.html#gitserver_install) url but I could not understand how will I add IP address of my mac.

Comment: You cannot do what you want to do.  Either you use bitbucket as your *remote* for all the developers, and files and uploaded to their site, or you don't.

Answer (score 1):

BitBucket is the remote server that would host your code. Since you don't want to use a remote server, you're using just Git. Not BitBucket.

The IP address of you mac is what other team members will need to sync with the repository. They will also need ssh access to your mac.

When you're setting this up, since its on your local machine, you never need to ssh. Anywhere you see ssh, just replace it with the local path of the bare .git repository. For example, you might create the repository like this:

```
git init --bare /opt/git/example.git
```

When you push to this repository, it is like this:

```
mkdir gitexample
cd gitexample
git init
touch README
git add README
git commit -m 'first commit'
git remote add origin /opt/git/example.git
git push origin master
```

When other users push/pull from the repository, they need to use ssh with your Mac's IP address as in the example you linked (and obviously they will need to be on the same network).